# PagedResultList issue in grails 2

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I was using 1.3.7 before and constructor for PagedResultList in that PagedResultList  constructor was accepting list. So my code was

```
def result = [...]

def pagedResult = new PagedResultList(result)
```

now the constructor is changed as

```
PagedResultList(GrailsHibernateTemplate template, Criteria crit)
```

Can you please help me convert result list to PagedResultList in 2.x ?

Comment: I don't think `PagedResultList` was ever intended to be constructed directly outside of GORM methods.  The only thing that a `PagedResultList` gives you over a plain list is the `totalCount` property, which `new PagedResultList(result)` would not set anyway.  Or were you previously setting the `totalCount` after construction?

Comment: yes. I was setting totalCount after construction                    def pagedResult = new PagedResultList(result)
pagedResult.totalCount = distinctCount[0]

Answer (score 4):

`PagedResultList` appears to have been changed in Grails 2 to calculate the `totalCount` lazily on first access rather than the count having to be calculated up-front when it might not ultimately be required.  But it's 4 lines of Groovy to write your own drop-in replacement, thanks to the [`Delegate` AST transformation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Delegate+transformation):

```
class MyPagedResultList {
  @Delegate List theList
  int totalCount
}

// create one using new MyPagedResultList(theList:result, totalCount:total)
```

What the transformation does is automatically add all the methods of the delegate type (in this case `List`) to the target type (in this case `MyPagedResultList`), implemented by delegating to the delegate object. So it makes `MyPagedResultList` implement the `List` interface without having to write out all the relevant methods by hand.

Comment: This works as expected. Can you please elaborate why you used Delegate annotation?

Comment: @user1298426 I've added a bit more detail, and a link to the Groovy documentation page.